# Could this program which writes to a pipe be optimized for performance?

Tags: c

I made a sample program as a model for something which will need to calculate more complex task than a sample multiplication like it does right now. I was told this sample program I made could be optimized for better performance. Is there anything which could be improve in it? Maybe using more than a single pipe?

Currently the program fork a second process, the parent writes a variable to a pipe, the child read it and makes a calculation, write to the same pipe and the parents finally read the pipe when the child as finish it's execution.

```
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int multi(int var) {
   int status;
   int multi;
   int pfd[2];
   if ( pipe(pfd) < 0 ) {
           perror("pipe");
       exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
   }
   int pid = fork();
   if (pid < 0) {
       printf("fork error\n");
       exit(0);
   }
   if (pid>0) {
       write(pfd[1], &var, sizeof(var));
       wait(&status);
       read(pfd[0], &multi, sizeof(multi));
       close(pfd[0]);
   } else {
       read(pfd[0], &var, sizeof(var));
       multi = 10 * var;
       write(pfd[1], &multi, sizeof(multi));
       close(pfd[1]);
       int pidchild = getpid();
       kill(pidchild, 9);
   }
   return multi;
}

int main(void) {
   int x;
   fscanf(stdin, "%d", &x);
   printf("%d\n", multi(x));
   return 0;
}
```

Comment: Why the child is killing itself? It can `exit`, you know... Also the parent should `read` before `wait`ing.

Comment: So that there isn't a dupplication of the output. When I remove the kill, the program prints twice the same output.

Comment: Then you have a different problem.

Comment: Ok I changed the `kill` for and `exit` and the program still work. Just wondering if they was a program performance wise with this program. I will check out the `wait` location.

Comment: Pipes should be treated as unidirectional connections — otherwise, you run into problems controlling whether the writer on the pipe reads what it just wrote.  If you need information going to the child and coming from the child, you would probably be best served by two pipes, one for communication parent-to-child and the other for communication child-to-parent.  Be careful to close enough file descriptors in both parent and child.

Comment: Using the same pipe for communication in both directions is problematic. As both processes have both ends of the pipe open, it can result in an endlessly blocking `read` in one process if the other process ends unexpectedly. If you `write` or `read` bigger chunks of data your code must be able to handle the case that a single call to `read` or `write` processes less than the expected number of bytes. Check the return value of all functions and handle errors or whatever is indicated by the return value.

Comment: Do you need to `fork()` or could you use threads instead? Also, even if you fork, is there really a need to send `var` over the pipe? The child process gets a copy of everything at `fork()` time. And in the parent, if you are doing a blocking `read()` anyway, there is no need for calling `wait()` (especially not if you ignore its return value).

Comment: I need to use fork, and you are right, there really hasn't any need to send var over the pipe.